# Magical record: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I'm using MagicalRecord,

That's how I setup a coreData stack

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Magical record

    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"HITO.sqlite"];
```

That's how I use it

```
- (void)getQuizzessWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *quizzess, BOOL succes, NSError *error))completion {
    NSManagedObjectContext *backGroundContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newPrivateQueueContext] ;
    NSArray *quizzess = [Quiz MR_findAllInContext:backGroundContext];
    BlockSafeRun(completion, quizzess, YES, nil);
}
```

That's what I get

```
2015-06-17 19:50:53.358 HITO[6677:611576] Created new private queue context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x61f990>
2015-06-17 19:50:57.230 HITO[6677:611576] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'Quiz''
```

[image]

It seems like core data stack hasn't been set up properly.
I've tried changing methods for setting up core data stack, but haven't reached a success.

Comment: Do you actually have a 'Quiz' entity in your core date model?

Answer (score 1):

You should create Default context, then crete new private context, then set default context as parent for private context

```
NSManagedObjectContext *mainContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
NSManagedObjectContext *privateQueueContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newPrivateQueueContext];
[privateQueueContext setParentContext:mainContext];

NSArray *quizzess = = [Quiz MR_findAllInContext:privateQueueContext];
```